# Salesforce App follow stopped working

Tags: salesforce

My company has an app that they got off of the app exchange(Note: before I started) that allowed you to follow or unfollow large number of cases/accounts/opportunities etc in salesforce.com. Supposedly it worked before and now it isn't working. I need an idea of what is wrong with the code for each button. If I can't fix them, any ideas for a replacement app? The app is no longer on the app exchange any more.

here's the code for the follow button:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/18.0/connection.js")}

//EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINE TO ALTER THE CODE FOR OTHER OBJECTS. USE THE PICKLISTS ABOVE        TO SELECT FIELD TYPE = $ObjectType AND THE OBJECT NAME THEN REPLACE "$ObjectType.Case" WITH   YOUR NEW OBJECT NAME
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.Case)};

function LBox() {
var box = new parent.SimpleDialog("steve"+Math.random(), true);
parent.box = box;`

 box.setTitle("Follow Records");

box.createDialog();
box.setWidth(220);

box.setContentInnerHTML("<img src='/img/loading32.gif' alt='' /> Running");

box.setupDefaultButtons();`

box.show();
}

function CBox(){
box.setContentInnerHTML("You are now following "+follow_count+" records<br /><br /><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"box.hide();\">Close</a>");
}



if (records[0] == null) { 
alert("Please select at least one record.");
} 
else { 
var follow_count = 0;

LBox();

for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++){ 
var fol=new sforce.SObject("EntitySubscription");
fol.ParentId = records[i];
fol.SubscriberId = '{!User.Id}';

try{
sforce.connection.create([fol]); 
follow_count++;
}
catch(e){
alert(e);
}
}
CBox();

}

here's the unfollow button:
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/18.0/connection.js")}

// EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINE TO ALTER THE CODE FOR OTHER OBJECTS. USE THE PICKLISTS ABOVE TO SELECT FIELD TYPE = $ObjectType AND THE OBJECT NAME THEN REPLACE "$ObjectType.Case" WITH YOUR NEW OBJECT NAME
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS( $ObjectType.Case)};

// display running message popup
function LBox() {
var box = new parent.SimpleDialog("steve"+Math.random(), true);
parent.box = box;`

box.setTitle("Unfollow Records");

box.createDialog();
box.setWidth(220);

box.setContentInnerHTML("<img src='/img/loading32.gif' alt='' /> Running");

box.setupDefaultButtons();

box.show();
}

// display output message
function CBox(){
if (unfollow_count < records.length)
box.setContentInnerHTML("You have now unfollowed "+unfollow_count+" records. You were not following the other selected records. <br /><br /><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"box.hide();\">Close</a>");
else
box.setContentInnerHTML("You have now unfollowed "+unfollow_count+" records. <br /><br /><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"box.hide();\">Close</a>");
}

if (records[0] == null) {
alert("Please select at least one record.");
}
else {
var unfollow_count = 0;`

LBox();

try {
// find following records
var searchstring = "SELECT Id FROM EntitySubscription WHERE (ParentId IN (";
for (var i = 0; i < records.length - 1; i++) {
searchstring += "'" + records[i] + "',";
}
searchstring += "'" + records[records.length - 1] + "') AND SubscriberId ='{!User.Id}')";
var resultRecords = sforce.connection.query(searchstring).getArray("records");

// delete following records
var recordIds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < resultRecords.length; i++) {
recordIds.push(resultRecords[i].Id);
unfollow_count++;
}
sforce.connection.deleteIds(recordIds);
} catch(e) {
alert(e);
}

CBox();
}
```

The first error message has to do with permissions, I don't get this error because I have admin rights, the second error is only on the account tab's button. I'm more worried about the permissions problem, is there anything there about permissions. Any help is great!

Comment: Can you post the exact error messages?

Comment: What language is this in? Did you verify the app is correctly connecting to Salesforce and authenticating? Does the App have a license and if so did it expire? Or is it opensource? Installed out of a managed package (SFDC AppExchange?) And did you try to contact the App's developer?

Comment: @jordan.baucke it looks like javascript to me. user1552849, if it was working before, but stopped working for no reason, it suggests something has changed in the environment, plus if it's a app exchange app, I believe you cannot change the code. right? So even if you spot the bug or mistake, you can't fix it yourself, or have I got the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: grigriforce I will post the errors in a moment. jordan.baucke I didn't write the app so I'm not 100% what language, I also believe it is javascript. The app works on some objects on our site for me except the for one, my coworker is having a different error though. Like I said I will post both messages. I have very limited information since I just started and this was thrown on me. There was no license and the app's developer no longer supports it. Anup I agree I believe the newest Salesforce update may have cause the issue. I do have the code so I can change it if a solution is found.

Comment: This is the error my co worker is getting @grigriforce:
{faultcode:'sf:MALFORMED_QUERY',faultstring:'MALFORMED_QUERY:Implementation restriction: EntitySubscription only allows security evaluation for non-admin users when LIMIT is specified and at most 1000', detail:{MalformedQueryFault:{exceptionCode:'MALFORMED_QUERY',exceptionMessage:"Implementation restriction: EntitySubscriptiononly allows security evaluation for non-admin users when LIMIT is specified and at most 1000', row:'-1', column:'-1',},},}

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is a [throttle in SFDC](http://na12.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.pdf), you are limited to following only a certain number of records per user. If this app was designed as you described to mass-follow records, it's possible your hitting that throttle, which is kind of the impression I get from the error your co-worker is receiving about `at most 1000`, also if it worked before, it would make sense that you have maxed out a limit for the org/user

Comment: ps. lots of AppExchange apps don't account for these sort of unexpected circumstances after they've been installed. So it's certainly possible they didn't gracefully handle the throttle error.

Comment: That's weird because the app is made to unfollow records so you can avoid that limit. I would hope that even if you reached it you could unfollow to keep under it. The other thing is that the limit is 500, so I'm not sure where it is getting 1000.

Comment: Some of the throttles limit the number of results that can be processed in a particular context as well, so it's possible they're hitting one of those. Can you link to the App on the appexchange?

Comment: http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HjkJEAS

http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003GKAJEA4

Comment: Did you hand copy the javascript source for the custom button out that picture? or do you have it written out somewhere?

Comment: i believe they copied it from somewhere; it isn't from the picture because the picture doesn't have all the code. I'm sorry I'm not much help.

Answer (score 0):

Queries on EntitySubscription by users who aren't system admins must contain a LIMIT. If you change the query code in the button to the following it should work:

```
// find following records
var searchstring = "SELECT Id FROM EntitySubscription WHERE (ParentId IN (";
for (var i = 0; i < records.length - 1; i++) {
   searchstring += "'" + records[i] + "',";
}
searchstring += "'" + records[records.length - 1] + "') AND SubscriberId ='{!User.Id}') LIMIT 1000";
```

Comment: now my user is getting a different error
"A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was encountered: Box is not defined". Ideas?

Comment: Is this occurring with the follow button, unfollow button, or both?